# log4net to a class library

Tags: c#, log4net, class-library

I have a class library project attached to internet explorer (add-on for explorer), I want to log this class library with `log4net`, I added a `App.config` file to the project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="log4net.Config" value="log4net.config"/>
    <add key="log4net.Config.Watch" value="True"/>
  </appSettings>

  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppenderSize" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="FromLog4netLon.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <encoding value="utf-8" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date{ABSOLUTE} [%logger] %level - %message%newline%exception" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="FATAL" />
      <level value="WARN" />
      <level value="INFO" />
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppenderSize" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

And under `AssemblysInfo.cs` I added `[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]`

And inside my project I added

```
private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

And I try to write like:

```
log.Info("test log");
```

I also try to add this:

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"D:\IExtonsionsTests\1\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary.dll.config");
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(fi);
```

> But it doesn't write log file, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your file value is correct and the path really exists. You are missing the most important thing, the logger. Just insert this code after your appender:
(You can add more than one logger if you want to)

---

```
<logger name="STANDART" additivity="false">
        <level value="ALL"/>
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppenderSize"/>
    </logger>
```

---

### **Your code should look like this:**

```
public enum LoggerTypes
{
    STANDART = 0
}
public class Logger1
{
    private static readonly string _loggerConfigDic = "..\\..\\YOURFOLDER\\YOURFILENAME.xml";
    private static readonly List<string> _names = new List<string> { "STANDART" }; /*Logger names in config file*/

    public static ILog GetLogger(LoggerTypes loggerType)
    {
        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(_loggerConfigDic);
        XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(fileInfo);
        return LogManager.GetLogger(_names[(int)loggerType]);
    }
}

public class myClass
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        var logger = Logger1.GetLogger(LoggerTypes.STANDART);
        logger.Debug("your message here");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting `log4net:ERROR XmlHierarchyConfigurator: No appender named [AutomaticFileAppender] could be found`

Comment: That is how i named MY appender. Your appenders name is "RollingFileAppenderSize" So just change that name in the config and you are ready to go :) (I will edit the post so you can just copy paste it)

Comment: It seems like it worked. Thank you for marking the answer as correct. If you have any issue or question, feel free to ask (and if you need a LoggerClass I can show you mine) Happy Coding !

Comment: There you gooo ;-) YW